# Mindstorms EV3 Spinner factory complete code problem

Tags: ev3

I recently posted a question about the creation of My Block. Now I have another problem. I have written the code as described in the program description, and double checked it, but it still doesn't work. I'm sorry for the way that I've visualised the program, but it seemed the easiest way:

[Spinner Factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eox12.jpg)

Comment: I feel this is relevant from meta: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) I think your question cannot be considered very specific... Perhaps you can tell us what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I don't exactly know. I think it is the block GH_1, but I'm not sure

Comment: I know you're banned, but you should try selecting certain blocks at a time and press the run selected button. Keep trying this throughout the program until you get an error from either the EV3 Brick or the PC. More often than not it may come from the PC

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the EV3 education software can be downloaded for free

https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3/software

It includes the program for the spinner factory, perhaps you can study that program and compare it with your own implementation to find the problem

Alternatively and probably much more instructive, you could learn how to debug programs. For EV3 this is easiest with inserting sound alert or displaying values on the EV3 screen (with a wait block) during the steps of your program, you can find hints on how to debug a program here:

http://stemrobotics.cs.pdx.edu/sites/default/files/debug.pdf